# Is the sum of two sets out of a subspace in or not in that subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering  $\omega$ a subspace of V:

$$U \notin \omega$$
$$Z \notin \omega$$

It's true or false to say that: $$U + Z  \notin \omega$$?

I think that it's false. Because considering U and Z vectors, I can get the origin of U being a point that belongs to $\omega$ and the tip of Z being a point that belongs to $\omega$ too... So their sum will result in a vector that is in the subspace $\omega$.

Am I correct? Is it false because $\forall U,Z$ you can't assume their sum to be always out of $\omega$?

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, as sson as $\omega$ is a *proper* subspace of $V$, we can find $U\in V\setminus\omega$, let $Z=-U$, and have found a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these vectors

$U=M + L$ and $Z=M-L$ such that $L \notin \omega$ and $M \in \omega$. Clearly $U,Z \notin \omega$. But their sum $U+Z=2M$ is in $\omega$. So your assertion is false.

Comment: Simple explanation... I can assume that the same statement will be false under scalar multiplication right?

Comment: @BrunoReis If $\alpha U \in \omega$ then by properties of vector spaces (closure under scalar multiplication), $\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot \alpha U  = U \in \omega$. Thus, if $U \not\in \omega$, neither is any **non-zero** scalar multiple of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true that one cannot say that $U + Z \notin \omega$. For a concrete example, let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\omega = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$. Then $(1,\pm 1) \notin \omega$ however $(1,1) + (1,-1) \in \omega$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's false. For a simple concrete example: let $\mathbb{R}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ as the usual $xy$ plane. Then, $(0,0,1), (0,0,-1)$ are your $U$ and $Z$ respectively, and by construction, $U, Z \not\in \mathbb{R}^2 = \omega$. Yet, $U+Z = (0,0,1) + (0,0,-1) = (0,0,0) \in \omega$.